# Get a subset of a data set based on SRS of the unique values of a variable in SAS

Tags: sas, sampling

I have a data set with two variables `x` and `y`. `x` has four distinct values 1, 2, 3, and 4. I want to first take a simple random sample of size 2 from these 4 unique values and keep the corresponding rows.

Say, I get the SRS of 1, 2, then I will keep the first 7 rows as a new data set. If I get a SRS of 2 and 3, then I will keep the fifth to the eighth rows. Here is a simple example to start with. Thank you.

```
data dataone;
  input x y;
  datalines;
  1 3
  1 4
  1 5
  1 8
  2 3
  2 7
  2 9
  3 2
  4 8
  4 5
  ;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this one of two ways.

PROC SURVEYSELECT will do the work for you, if you do it in two steps: first give it a dataset of just X unique values, then merge to another dataset that has all values.

Alternately, you can do this in a datastep, where you first determine if you're going to take that X value, then take/not take the rows.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by x;
  call streaminit(7);
  retain need 2; *need 2 total;
  retain have 4; *have 4 total - this could be determined programatically.;
  retain keep;  *and these three could all be one retain statement, this is just more readable;
  if first.x then do;
    if need/have ge rand('Uniform') then keep=1;
    else keep=0;
    need + -keep;
    have + -1;
    put need= have= _t=;
  end;
  if keep;
run;
```

This is a modified form of [Reservoir Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).  It works out to identical results of SRS, even though the odds of taking any one X appear to be different.

Comment: Thank you. Could you say a little more on the first method using SURVEYSELECT? I don't know how to get the unique values using either TABULATE or FREQ.

Comment: If you know how to output a dataset by PROC FREQ then you know how to get unique values for a variable: just PROC FREQ on that variable out to a file.  Presto, unique values.